# Can I use nest a void inside another void in Java?

Tags: java, nested, void

So, here's my code.

```
public class Cay {
    public void Mesaj() {
        System.out.println("Başka bir sınıftan merhabalar!");

        public void Araba() {
            System.out.println("Selamlar Tekrardan.");
        }
    }
}
```

The `public void Mesaj()` works pretty well at my other class. But `public void Araba()` doesn't work. It gives a compilation error.

> - void[] is an invalid type
>
>   - Illegal modifier for parameter Araba; only final is permitted
>   - Syntax error, insert "[ ]" to complete Dimension
>   - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
>   - Syntax error on token "Araba", AnnotationName expected after this token

I searched but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` after the `Mesaj` method.

Comment: but how are you calling the araba method??

Comment: you cannot nest function definitions in Java

Comment: @4castle I didn't add them here.In Eclipse I placed them correctly.

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the code is correct. Ideally, we should be able to run your code and see the issue you describe. See: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Your `Mesaj()` function is missing its closing brace.

```
public class Cay {
  public void Mesaj(){
    System.out.println("Başka bir sınıftan merhabalar!");
  }

  public void Araba(){
    System.out.println("Selamlar Tekrardan.");
  }
}
```

Comment: I just didn't add them here.In Eclipse ı placed all closing braces.

Comment: You had the _correct number_ of braces, but not necessarily in the correct place. The scope of a method (such as "Mesaj") must be closed before the next method starts.

Answer (score 0):

A class can have multiple member functions, be it of the type void/String or any other, but the scope of one function cannot contain another function and hence the error. So remove the brace from the end and add one before the start of Araba()